# How to target a specific element within a div id?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to build a HTML/CSS periodic table. I have this as my HTML code:

```
<div id="Hydrogen">
<p>1</p>
H
Hydrogen
1.00794
</div>
```

and this is my CSS code:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#hydrogen {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-radius */
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* box-shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

How do I target the `<p>1</p>` tag in my #hydrogen ID? Basically, I want to display a 1 on the top-left corner of the div cell. Also, is this the best method of doing this, or is there a easier way?

Comment: `#hydrogen > p` to get to your p. See this link for more details on selectors http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: You can target the <p> with document.querySelector('#Hydrogen p') in Javascript

Comment: You can simply state the div id and then the element inside by saying
#hydrogen p{ example: 5px}

Answer (score 4):

If it’s the only p element within that div, then sinply

```
#Hydrogen p { … }
```

Otherwise, if it’s the first one,

```
#Hydrogen p:first-child { … }
```

This are absolute CSS selector basics – so you should perhaps read some tutorials on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
#hydrogen p { position:absolute; left:0; top:0;}
```

should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the command "span".

Example:

```
<p><span>1</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
span { font-size:14; }
```

You can expend this code with "id" or "class".

---

ID-Example:

```
<p><span id="name">1</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
#name { font-size:14; }
```

---

Class-Example:

```
<p><span class="large">1</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
.large { font-size:14; }
```

Comment: `p` can’t be a child of `span`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with:

```
#hydrogen p{..}
```

but as you said you want to do periodic table so you will have 103 elements so than for every p-element you will have to write:

```
#hydrogen p{..}
#helium p{...}
#lithium p{...}
```

... and so 103 times, same thing with divs with Id's

Better solution would be to give p and div class name

```
.atomic-number{...}
.grid-cell{...}

<div class="grid-cell">
   <p class="atomic-number">1</p>
      H
   Hydrogen
   1.00794
</div>
```

You can style all elements with just two lines of CSS

## EDIT

Create rows, and position elements inside them.
For example float all grid cells left, if you need something to stick on the right side add class="right" (1st row) you probably will have to change colours same way, also you can create invisible cells and fill space with them (2nd row)

http://fiddle.jshell.net/tH7Pq/1/

If you want you can read more about classes, id's and selectors here:

[Id's and classes](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

[multiple classes](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/)

[child-and-sibling](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Comment: Ah, this seems like a much more efficient solution. Thank you.

Comment: The problem with this method is that I still have to individually position each element correctly. So I'm still going to need to have a id selector for each element. Or is there a better way to better position each element?